# Laravel custom DB Databable

Tags: database, laravel-5, dataset

I'm interested in having a Table in my Laravel database, where I can read/write from.

However, I don't want it do be affected by `php artisan migrate:fresh` or `php artisan migrate:refresh` commands.

I want to use it as a custom storage for a dataset, which will be imported in the database and updated when needed but only be readable by Laravel.

Comment: the only thing that is come to my mind on the first place, is to create a route `/create/customdbtable/` and insite the method use `schema` to create the table with all options, and then I think will not be touch by migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that is come to my mind on the first place, is to create a route /create/customdbtable/ and insite the method use schema to create the table with all options, and then I think will not be touch by migration – Plamen Penchev